# I was trying write permissions specs for CanCan by RyanBates but got error "uninitialized constant Ability::CanCan"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, cancan

I dont think this issue [CanCan uninitialized constant Ability::CanCan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921762/cancan-uninitialized-constant-abilitycancan) addresses my problem.

According to CanCan Its not hard to test the `Abilities` . I followed https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities to write specs:

When I try the following command

```
bundle exec rspec spec/cancan/ability.rb
```

I get the following error

```
/projects/ATS/app/models/ability.rb:2:in `<class:Ability>': uninitialized constant Ability::CanCan (NameError)
        from /home/shiva/projects/ATS/app/models/ability.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/shiva/projects/ATS/spec/cancan/ability.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shiva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cancan-1.6.10/lib/cancan.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/shiva/projects/ATS/spec/rails_helper.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/shiva/projects/ATS/spec/cancan/ability.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

My code in `spec/cancan/ability.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Ability, type: :model do
  subject(:ability) {Ability.new(user)}
  let(:user) {nil}
  context 'Logged in as CSA' do
    let(:org) {create(:organization)}
    let(:user) {create(:user, organization: org, role_ids: [Role::ROLE_CSA])}
    describe 'Not Permitted' do
      it 'to visit /admins' do
          it {is_expected.to be_able_to(:manage, Workflow.new)}
      end

    end
  end
end
```

and code in snippet in `models/ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, url, admin_session_id, my_applicant_id)
    if user.present?
      user.roles[0].permissions_by_organization(user).each do |permission|
        case permission.subject_class
```

#### Version Details of components

- Rails 4.0.4
- rspec-core (3.1.7)
- rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
- rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
- rspec-rails (3.1.0)
- rspec-support (3.1.2)
- cancan (1.6.10)

Comment: you might want to try out [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for Rails 4. It is the continued version of CanCan since it is out of date.

Comment: I would have but I am currently on a project running for many years so I am not allowed to upgrade to CanCanCan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.

The issue was the `filename` of the `spec` file
It should have been
`spec/cancan/ability_spec.rb` but it was
`spec/cancan/ability.rb`

and I should have invoked
`bundle exec rspec spec/cancan/ability_spec.rb`

For more details please visit this link [RSpec naming conventions for files and directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180003/rspec-naming-conventions-for-files-and-directory-structure#answer-14208073)